# "Ghost" factors when subsetting a dataframe

Tags: r, shiny, r-caret, shinydashboard

I have a dataframe (**TablaTotal**) with the following levels:

```
> levels(TablaTotal$Enfermedad)
[1] "Disferlina" "OPMD"       "Laminas"    "Pompe"      "Fshd"       "SarcoG"     "Calpaina"   "Distrofina" "ANO5"
```

And I want to filter it by levels. The levels to filter are chosen in a checkboxGroupInput (**TablasSeleccionadas**):

```
checkboxGroupInput("TablasSeleccionadas", 
   h3("Entrenar para:"),
   choices = list("Disferlina" = "Disferlina", 
                  "OPMD" = "OPMD", 
                  "Laminas" = "Laminas",
                  "Pompe"="Pompe",
                  "Fshd"="Fshd",
                  "SarcoG"="SarcoG",
                  "Calpaina"="Calpaina",
                  "Distrofina"="Distrofina",
                  "ANO5"="ANO5")
)
```

I create the subset **SubTablaTotal** through the *subset()* function:

```
SubTablaTotal <<- subset(TablaTotal,Enfermedad %in%c(input$TablasSeleccionadas))
```

And apparently the result is valid, at least it looks ok when I view the dataframe through *view(SubTablaTotal)*: I only have the levels chosen on the check boxes. But when I check the levels, I get the following result:

```
> levels(SubTablaTotal$Enfermedad)
[1] "Disferlina" "OPMD"       "Laminas"    "Pompe"      "Fshd"       "SarcoG"     "Calpaina"   "Distrofina" "ANO5"
```

I do not expect to have all levels. Then when creating a *DataPartition* i get the following warning:

> Warning in createDataPartition(SubTablaTotal$Enfermedad, p =
>   input$indiceP,  :   Some classes have no records ( Fshd, SarcoG,
>   Calpaina, Distrofina, ANO5 ) and these will be ignored

And when trying to train a model I get the following error:

> Error in : One or more factor levels in the outcome has no data:
>   'Fshd', 'SarcoG', 'Calpaina', 'Distrofina', 'ANO5'

**Am I missing any point in the subset() functionality?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In `subset` use `drop=TRUE`

Comment: @A.Suliman No aparent changes on the result, thanks for answering

Answer (score -1):

Following A. Suliman comment, this issue can be fixed with

```
SubTablaTotal$Enfermedad<-factor(SubTablaTotal$Enfermedad)
```